# How to pass the value of Access-Field to a Textbox?

Tags: vb.net

I'm using VB2005 and I got a message error in a runtime: ***Abstract does not belong to table tblBooks.*** I don't think that the problem is its datatype. I'm currently using MEMO datatype because I need to load it more than the capacity of string. Is it possible to use this code in order to accomplish it? `txtAbstractInfo.Text = MyTable.Tables(0).Rows(Counter)("Abstract").ToString`

**txtAbstractInfo** is the name of my textbox and my field's name is **Abstract**. I'm a newbie in VB 2005 and I am honestly unfamiliar with this kind of error. Please help me out!

Comment: Seems like "Abstract" is not a field in table "tblBooks" and you are trying to reference it.

Comment: Thanks for the response... what do you mean? We are given a MS-Access database, and honestly the **Abstract** is included in my **tblBooks**. I can't get the hang of this error. I'v actually thought about that previously for the error shows me up that **Abstract** doesn't belong to **tblBooks** but regrettably that column is already in table. I already went all out, but the message keeps on popping up...

Comment: The problem isn't about passing the value to the Textbox... it's about getting the value of the "Abstract" field.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, actually I don't know the cause of your problem, so let's begin with that, I suggest that you change the name of the field in the database from "Abstract" to "Abstract1" just to make sure that the name is not a reserved word, so run your program with this change.

If problem persists  then change the memo type to string (or text I don't remember) and run the program again. I think that with this changes we could have a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: @SimonBesner what should I do now? Abstract contains almost hundred of characters and I was warning that changing its datatype into text could produce a partial value.